# Any difference in GWT between Collections.emptyList() and new ArrayList()

Tags: gwt

It is a known fact, that in Java it is good practice to return Collections.emptyList instead of empty ArrayList object. When writing for GWT, how does GWT compiler treat this emptyList - is it as efficient to use as ArrayList or it doesn't make any sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collections.emptyList()` might be better than `new ArrayList()` (compare [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.3/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/Collections.java#27) to [that](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.3/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/ArrayList.java)), but I believe it actually doesn't matter (`ArrayList` is probably used anyway –it's used internally in widgets–, so it won't be optimized out if you use `Collections.emptyList()`, and the `EmptyList` is so *small* that it's not worth optimizing it out; and again it might also be used somewhere by code you didn't write, so…).

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't care for micro-optimizations unless you **have** a performance/code-size issue that needs fixing. *“[Premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) is the root of all evil.”* (Donald Knuth)